Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
After installing react-native-reanimated package Iam getting that error in building the project.
version of react-native-reanimated = ^3.4.2
version of react-native = 0.73.4
error is saying ninja entering my directory of node_modules..
